# Grails - Filter not firing when controller is specified

Tags: grails

So I am trying to specify a filter for a particular controller of mine, but it never seems to enter the 'before' clause of the filter. However, if I specify the controller and action to be anything, it does seem to work.

```
secure(controller:'*', action:'*') {
    before = {
        print "test"       
    }
}
```

This seems to work, but when I try

```
secure(controller:'DocumentPart', action:'*') {
    before = {
        print "test"
}
}
```

Nothing seems to occur. The controller and filter are contained in a package of the same name. I created the filter with the `grails` `create-filters` command. I have tried not specifying the package, making it resort to the default package, but I still have the same issue. Anyone know what is causing this?

**Edit**: I am an idiot, thanks Joshua for the input

Comment: Use documentPart not DocumentPart

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think the name you are specifying for the controller is incorrect.  If the controller is DocumentPartController then the value you specify in the filter should be documentPart.

See http://grails.org/doc/latest/guide/theWebLayer.html#filters for examples.